# External fingerprint scanner with Android Emulator

Tags: android

How can I use external fingerprint scanner with AVD in android studio?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: is there any way we can debug external fingerprint scanner? when we connect our external fingerprint device to the mobile's port, we don't have any option to debug it further as the only port which could connect to the computer has plugged with the fingerprint scanner. Here comes this question? do anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an external fingerprint scanner with AVD, sadly. Your best option would be to deploy the app to your existing Android device that has a fingerprint scanner.